# Fivefold output from istringstream

Tags: c++, output, istringstream

I would like to outout each line after a certain substring is detected. Somehow I get a fivefold output for `iss`. Here's my code:

```
    //load all data from txt
        string data;
        std::ifstream infile("SavedData.txt");
        while (std::getline(infile, data)) {
            std::istringstream iss(data);
            string d;
            while (iss >> d) {
                //extract substring
                unsigned firstBracket = data.find("(");
                unsigned lastBracket = data.find(")");
                string coordSynth = data.substr(firstBracket + 1, lastBracket - firstBracket - 1);
                cout << coordSynth << endl;
            }
        }
```

The output right now is like:

```
0.0, 45.0, -390.0
0.0, 45.0, -390.0
0.0, 45.0, -390.0
0.0, 45.0, -390.0
0.0, 45.0, -390.0
0.0, 45.0, -314.3
0.0, 45.0, -314.3
0.0, 45.0, -314.3
0.0, 45.0, -314.3
0.0, 45.0, -314.3
etc.
```

Actually I just want

```
0.0, 45.0, -390.0
0.0, 45.0, -314.3
0.0, 45.0, -277.3
etc.
```

And no, in the txt file there aren't duplcates. This file looks like this:

```
0001(0.0, 45.0, -390.0).png 
0003(0.0, 45.0, -314.3).png 
0007(0.0, 45.0, -277.3).png (and so on...)
```

Comment: What does `SavedData.txt` look like?

Comment: 0001(0.0, 45.0, -390.0).png
0003(0.0, 45.0, -314.3).png
0007(0.0, 45.0, -277.3).png
and so on

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question with some formatting so it is readable.

Comment: @NathanOliver did it!

Comment: You're finding/outputting the parenthesized expression once for each successful invocation of `iss >> d`.  What is the `while (iss >> d)` loop supposed to do?

Comment: @G.M. in the `while(iss >> d)` loop I extract the substring from the string as the comment above says.

Comment: Yes but it means you get the substring far too often.  See the answer by @NathanOliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that

```
unsigned firstBracket = data.find("(");
unsigned lastBracket = data.find(")");
string coordSynth = data.substr(firstBracket + 1, lastBracket - firstBracket - 1);
cout << coordSynth << endl;
```

Which is the logic to get `0.0, 45.0, -390.0` from `0001(0.0, 45.0, -390.0).png` is inside a while loop that you're not even doing anything with.  That loop is going to execute 5 times for every line of input (because there are five "sub strings") so you get 5 outputs.  All you need to do is get rid of the while loop since you're not doing anything with the individual strings contained in the line.  That gives you something like

```
int main() 
{   
    std::string data;
    std::istringstream infile("0001(0.0, 45.0, -390.0).png\n0003(0.0, 45.0, -314.3).png\n0007(0.0, 45.0, -277.3).png\n");
    while (std::getline(infile, data)) {
        std::istringstream iss(data);
        std::string d;
        //extract substring
        unsigned firstBracket = data.find("(");
        unsigned lastBracket = data.find(")");
        std::string coordSynth = data.substr(firstBracket + 1, lastBracket - firstBracket - 1);
        std::cout << coordSynth << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!